# Cocos2d-x v3.1 for WinPhone 8 auto change texture after resumed from background

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have some sprites in my game (for Windows Phone 8). These are my steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open game
2. Play (this is an optional step)
3. Press `Windows` button to send game to background
4. Press `Back` button to resume game

The problem is: After the game has resumed, some sprites exchange textures, some sprites go black (like there is no texture being bound).

I'm using cocos2dx version 3.1. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to give out a lot more information than my game does not run. Put screenshots, code, anything that can help us determine what can be done to solve your problem, otherwise we are just speculating.

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading your gfx again in applicationWillEnterForeground().  This works for me, but I'm still seeing some issues with rendermodes occasionally not being quite correct after resuming.